# Listings short title doesn't work

Tags: listings, captions

Hey guys I follow the instructions to create a short title with the package listings.

My code looks like:

```
\begin{lstlisting}[caption={[Beispiel JSON Array mit zwei Objekten]{Beispiel JSON Array mit zwei Objekten Quelle: \autocite[8]{crockford_application/json_2006}}}
\label{lst:json},captionpos=b,language=JavaScript, frame=single]
[
    {
        "precision": "zip",
        "Latitude": 37.7668,
        "Longitude": -122.3959,
        "Address": "",
        "City": "SAN FRANCISCO",
        "State": "CA",
        "Zip": "94107",
        "Country": "US"
    },
    {
        "precision": "zip",
        "Latitude": 37.371991,
        "Longitude": -122.026020,
        "Address": "",
        "City": "SUNNYVALE",
        "State": "CA",
        "Zip": "94085",
        "Country": "US"
    }

\end{lstlisting}
```

But my output shows the short title and the long title.

[image]

Does anyone have a idea why this happens?

Full Example:

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper,titlepage,pdftex,chapterprefix=true]{scrbook}

\usepackage[autooneside=false,headsepline,markcase=noupper]{scrlayer-scrpage}
\automark[subsection]{section}
\pagestyle{scrheadings}
\clearscrheadfoot
\ofoot[\pagemark]{\pagemark}
%\ohead{\ifstr{\rightbotmark}{\leftmark}{}{\rightbotmark}}
\ihead{\leftmark}
\usepackage{amssymb}
%Colspan und Rowspan ermöglichen
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{multirow}
%Grafiken einbinden
\usepackage{graphicx} 
\usepackage{epstopdf}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{floatflt}
\usepackage{wrapfig}
\usepackage{subfigure} 
%\usepackage{eurosym}
%Icons
%\usepackage{bbding}
\usepackage{marvosym}
%Plots mit Latex erstellen
\usepackage{pgfplots}
%Graphen aller Art erstellen
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{patterns}
%Quellcode darstellen 
\usepackage{listings}
\usepackage{color}
\definecolor{middlegray}{rgb}{0.5,0.5,0.5}
\definecolor{lightgray}{rgb}{0.8,0.8,0.8}
\definecolor{orange}{rgb}{0.8,0.3,0.3}
\definecolor{yac}{rgb}{0.6,0.6,0.1}
\definecolor{darkgray}{rgb}{.4,.4,.4}
\definecolor{purple}{rgb}{0.65, 0.12, 0.82}
\renewcommand{\lstlistingname}{Auflistung}
\renewcommand{\lstlistlistingname}{Auflistungen}
\lstdefinelanguage{JavaScript}{
    keywords={typeof, new, true, false, catch, function, return, null, catch, switch, var, if, in, while, do, else, case, break},
    keywordstyle=\color{blue}\bfseries,
    ndkeywords={class, export, boolean, throw, implements, import, this},
    ndkeywordstyle=\color{darkgray}\bfseries,
    identifierstyle=\color{black},
    sensitive=false,
    comment=[l]{//},
    morecomment=[s]{/*}{*/},
    commentstyle=\color{purple}\ttfamily,
    stringstyle=\color{red}\ttfamily,
    morestring=[b]',
    morestring=[b]"
}
\lstset{
    basicstyle=\scriptsize\ttfamily,
    keywordstyle=\bfseries\ttfamily\color{orange},
    stringstyle=\color{green}\ttfamily,
    commentstyle=\color{middlegray}\ttfamily,
    emph={square}, 
    emphstyle=\color{blue}\texttt,
    emph={[2]root,base},
    emphstyle={[2]\color{yac}\texttt},
    showstringspaces=false,
    flexiblecolumns=false,
    tabsize=2,
    numbers=left,
    numberstyle=\tiny,
    numberblanklines=false,
    stepnumber=1,
    numbersep=10pt,
    xleftmargin=15pt,
    numberbychapter=true,
    breaklines=true
}
%Abbildungen mit Kapitelnummern
%\usepackage{chngcntr}
%\counterwithin{figure}{section}
%\counterwithin{table}{section}
%\counterwithin{lstlisting}{section}
\usepackage{caption3}
%Abkürzungsverzeichnis
%\usepackage{acronym}
%Deutsche Bezeichnungen und Umlaute
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{ae}
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
%\usepackage{lmodern}
%\usepackage[ngerman]{translator}
%Einstellungen für die Tiefe der Überschriften
\setcounter{secnumdepth}{5}
\setcounter{tocdepth}{3} 
%Zeilenabstand
\usepackage{setspace}
%\makeatletter
% Damit die letzte (\botmark) statt der ersten (\firstmark) Marke auf
% einer Seite für die "rechte Marke" genommen wird:
\providecommand*{\rightbotmark}{\expandafter\@rightmark\botmark\@empty\@empty}
%\makeatother
\usepackage{xcolor} 
%Haken und Kreuze deffinieren
\usepackage{pifont}% http://ctan.org/pkg/pifont
\newcommand{\cmark}{\ding{51}}%
\newcommand{\xmark}{\ding{55}}%
\newcommand{\ccmark}{\color{green}\ding{51}\color{black}}%
\newcommand{\cxmark}{\color{red}\ding{55}\color{black}}%
\usepackage{framed} 
\newenvironment{balken}{% minimale Abwandlung von leftbar 
  \def\FrameCommand##1{\textcolor{red}{\vrule width 3pt} \hspace{10pt}##1}% 
  \MakeFramed {\advance\hsize-\width \FrameRestore}}% 
 {\endMakeFramed} 
\newcommand*{\tip}{\hspace{-25pt}\colorbox{red}{\textbf{\textcolor{white}{ Hinweis\\ }}}} 

%Literaturverzeichnis laden
\input{literaturVz.tex}
%Glossar einbinden
\usepackage[colorlinks]{hyperref}%Farbige Links
%\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage[xindy,
nonumberlist, %keine Seitenzahlen anzeigen
acronym,      %ein Abkürzungsverzeichnis erstellen
toc          %Einträge im Inhaltsverzeichnis
]      %im Inhaltsverzeichnis auf section-Ebene erscheinen
{glossaries}
\makeglossaries

\begin{lstlisting}[caption={[Beispiel JSON Array mit zwei Objekten]{Beispiel JSON Array mit zwei Objekten Quelle: \autocite[8]{crockford_application/json_2006}}}
\label{lst:json},captionpos=b,language=JavaScript, frame=single]
[
    {
        "precision": "zip",
        "Latitude": 37.7668,
        "Longitude": -122.3959,
        "Address": "",
        "City": "SAN FRANCISCO",
        "State": "CA",
        "Zip": "94107",
        "Country": "US"
    },
    {
        "precision": "zip",
        "Latitude": 37.371991,
        "Longitude": -122.026020,
        "Address": "",
        "City": "SUNNYVALE",
        "State": "CA",
        "Zip": "94085",
        "Country": "US"
    }
]
\end{lstlisting}
\end{document}
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Welcome, the instructionn doesn't work. `documentclass` is missing, there is no document environment etc. We cannot reproduce your issue.

Comment: I updated the question an add an full example.

Comment: I refuse to run this code a second time. Put a real minimal working example into your question.

Answer (score 2):

I found the error by searching for another problem.

```
\begin{lstlisting}[caption={[Beispiel JSON Array mit zwei Objekten]{Beispiel JSON Array mit zwei Objekten Quelle: \autocite[8]{crockford_application/json_2006}}}
\label{lst:json},captionpos=b,language=JavaScript, frame=single]
```

has to be:

```
   \begin{lstlisting}[caption={[Beispiel JSON Array mit zwei Objekten]{Beispiel JSON Array mit zwei Objekten Quelle: \autocite[8]{crockford_application/json_2006}}}
    ,label={lst:json},captionpos=b,language=JavaScript, frame=single]
```

so you need to change `\label{}` to `label={}` than all works like expected. This also fix the error that the references got wrong numbers.